# How to use an existing database to authenticate users in GeoNetwork

Tags: authentication, geonetwork

By default GeoNetwork stores users and groups in two tables named `users` and `usergroups` in the configured database, in my case a PostGIS database.

For our webgis application we have already an existing database with users, groups and roles. Is it possible to use the same database to authenticate users in GeoNetwork as well (preferably without recompiling GeoNetwork)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to connect GeoNetwork to different authentication systems like LDAP or CAS, which is the recommended way of sharing users between different apps:

https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/en/administrator-guide/managing-users-and-groups/authentication-mode.html

But probably you are talking about a customized database with users and groups. There is no generic way to do this (and probably it is not recommended), but you can try to use views on your database to try to mimic geoNetwork user tables using your own data:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html

If you use views, remember that you will have to create special triggers if you want to be able to administer users from the geoNetwork UI.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a customized user database. Currently the most promising solution is to work with views and a custom PasswordEncoder and / or to rewrite the user services and configure these custom services in config.xml.

Comment: Remember that geoNetwork uses spring-security. If your app also uses this, maybe you can connect them. If you are trying to use a real production geoNetwork with existing users, I strongly advice you to move to some authentication/authorization system like LDAP instead of using your own.